# How to search multi-language items with elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

So I have rails API app which uses Globalization Gem

I have and `Article` model which has `id, created_at and updated_at,` and this model has `article_translations` table which contains `title_en and title_ar` same applies for body and except

I set up Elasticsearch and it's working but with one language only

this is my concern file

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

module Searchable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    include Elasticsearch::Model
    include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

    mapping do
      # Also tried using
      # indexes :title, type: :text

      indexes :title_en, type: :text
      indexes :body_en, type: :text
      indexes :excerpt_en, type: :text
      indexes :title_ar, type: :text
      indexes :body_ar, type: :text
      indexes :excerpt_ar, type: :text
    end

    def self.search(query)
      # build and run search
      params = {
        query: {
          bool: {
            should: [
              { match: { title: { query: query, boost: 8, fuzziness: "AUTO" } }},
              { match: { body: { query: query, boost: 6, fuzziness: "AUTO" } }},
              { match: { excerpt: { query: query, boost: 4, fuzziness: "AUTO" } }},
            ]
          }
        },
      }

      self.__elasticsearch__.search(params)
    end
  end
end
```

Now when i use `Article.search('MyQuery')` it searches only on one language, the language which was set when `Article.import(force: true)` ran

So if i ran the above command which `I18n.locale = :en` it will index the english data, same for arabic

Since Globalization here works as following
`Article.first.title` will return `.title_en` with english locale and `.title_ar` with arabic locale which is set by user, of course we don't add the `_en` or the `_ar`, just `title`

what if i want to index both languages to be able to search in both `title_en` and `title_ar` when i send a query ?

Here is the index created

[image]

and this is after adding `title_en` & `title_ar` but they are ignored after importing

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you search in both title_en and title_ar, The query will search on both `title_en` and `title_ar` and you will get the results from both fields if there is any match. And elasticsearch will calculate the scores and sort the result documents.

Comment: Well, Maybe ES searches in both `_en` and `_ar`, but the issue maybe in the `Article.import`, because after importing while `I18n.locale = :en` it imports english data and searches fine, same if i import while `I18n is :ar`, and it returns AR data just fine, it's just importing one language only, also after importing the `:en`, and searching in AR, it returns 0 results, as it imported empty `title_ar`, and populated `title_en`, i think something is wrong with indexes, for some reason i think it imports the corresponding language into `title` attribute in index

Comment: I believe that the index already has articles in both Arabic and English. The `Article.import` filters the results during search time.

Comment: Any clue what could be the issue ? I'm really stuck on there and i still can't get both language to get into the index, I tried no to run this `Article.search('englihh')` and i mean this typo, and i got a result, then i tried `Article.search('englihh').first.title` i got `English Title`, and when i tried `.title_en` or `.title_ar`, it returned `undefined method `title_en' for #<Elasticsearch::Model` so it's not indexed in both languages, i removed the whole mapping and it got the attribute title on it's own, i guess it's coming from `translates :title` in model, but what about the values ?

Comment: Also when i tried `Article.search('foo').records.first` i could use `.title_en .title_ar`, thing is i can't get a result if i searched in arabic because the index contains the english value only under `title`

Comment: I have updated the post with a screen of the created index, that shows my issue, that we need `title_en` and `title_ar` instead of just `title` but i can't figure out how to do it

Comment: I have figured it out, and posted the answer, Thank you :)

Comment: Happy to hear you find it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i did it!

I'm not sure if it's the best way to do it or not but now it's working as it should with both languages :)

```rb
module Searchable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    include Elasticsearch::Model
    include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

    # I Don't need this anymore because
    # it's overridden on the as_indexed_json method
    #
    # mapping do
    #   indexes :title, type: :text
    #   indexes :title_en, type: :text
    #   indexes :body_en, type: :text
    #   indexes :excerpt_en, type: :text
    #   indexes :title_ar, type: :text
    #   indexes :body_ar, type: :text
    #   indexes :excerpt_ar, type: :text
    # end

    def self.search(query)
      # build and run search
      params = {
        query: {
          bool: {
            should: [
              { match: { title_en: { query: query, boost: 8, fuzziness: "AUTO" } }},
              { match: { title_ar: { query: query, boost: 8, fuzziness: "AUTO" } }},
              { match: { body_en: { query: query, boost: 6, fuzziness: "AUTO" } }},
              { match: { body_ar: { query: query, boost: 6, fuzziness: "AUTO" } }},
              { match: { excerpt_en: { query: query, boost: 4, fuzziness: "AUTO" } }},
              { match: { excerpt_ar: { query: query, boost: 4, fuzziness: "AUTO" } }}
            ]
          }
        },
      }

      self.__elasticsearch__.search(params)
    end

    def as_indexed_json(options = nil)
      self.as_json(
        only: %i[title_en title_ar body_en body_ar excerpt_en excerpt_ar],
        methods: %i[title_en title_ar body_en body_ar excerpt_en excerpt_ar]
      )
    end
  end
end
```